# How can I undo deleted comment on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, comments, data-recovery

I tried to edit a YouTube comment and instead click on delete:

[image]

After clicking on delete I get a notification that the comment was deleted but I didn't see any undo option:

[image]

How can I undo delete comment on YouTube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no "undo" functionality on YouTube for deleted comments. Deleted comments are instantly deleted upon clicking on **<kbd>`Delete`</kbd>** button. You can request the "undo" feature under 
**Send feedback** option:

[image]